# Why did Gamora give in?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

> Gamora gives the soul stone's location up to stop Thanos torturing Nebula.

Gamora & Nebula are never portrayed as being very close, and Gamora's hero-journey is "a work in progress".

> If she'd held out, Thanos would have had to find it himself and, more importantly, might not have had Gamora around to sacrifice for it. Saving half the Universe is worth holding out over, isn't it?

Comment: One other comment, both your questions seem to elicit opinion: `Saving half the Universe is worth holding out over, isn't it?` I suggest you keep your questions purely objective asking about motives in the films as opposed to suggesting opinions.

Answer (score 10):

Because Gamora and Nebula care for one another as sisters.

In *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2*

> **GAMORA:** I’m not the one who just flew across the universe because I wanted to win!
>   **NEBULA:** Don’t tell me what I want!
>   **GAMORA:** I don’t have to because you make it obvi -
>   **NEBULA:** YOU WERE THE ONE WHO WANTED TO WIN, I JUST WANTED A SISTER!
>
> **NEBULA:** I’ll help them by killing Thanos.
>   **GAMORA:** I don’t know if that’s possible.
>   **Nebula:** *shrugs*  maybe. 
>   She turns to leave. But Gamora grabs
>   her, perhaps too roughly. Nebula turns, ready to snap.
>   And Gamora EMBRACES her. Nebula does not know how to react.
>   **GAMORA:** You’ll always be my sister.

Source: [waltdisneystudiosawards.com](https://www.waltdisneystudiosawards.com/media/scripts/GotG2.pdf), text also backed up on [Transcripts Wiki](http://transcripts.wikia.com/wiki/Guardians_of_the_Galaxy_Vol._2) (though the first bit doesn't list who says what)

As we can see, despite it seeming as if they hate one another, the two love each other dearly, which means that in *Infinity Wars* Gamora is watching Thanos torture someone she loves.

Comment: Gamora is a trained assassin and highly intelligent. Why would she put one life regardless of who it is in front of half the universe? She should've shrugged her shoulders and said "Oh well, this is what you chose and I'm choosing to not buy into it. I will not feel guilt about your choice to torture your own daughter."